# FitNesse: Get FIT test column names in an array

Tags: fitnesse

Is there a way to grab the column names for the following FIT test into a list or array?

This is required for a fixture where the number of columns is not known beforehand.

E.g. in the example below there are just 2 columns but this can vary.

```
|myfixture    |
|col1  |Col2  |
|value1|value2|
|value3|value4|
```

There is a need to generate a dynamic list of columns.

Comment: Yes, there is.  Depends on your environment. What are you using: Java, .NET, etc, Fit or Slim test system?

Comment: I am using Java. I am trying to create a function for concatenating values stored in the columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the column headings when you extend Fixture:

```
public class MyFixture extends Fixture {
    public override void doRows(Parse rows) {
        for (Parse cell = rows.Parts; cell != null; cell = cell.More) {
            // cell iterates over the column heading cells
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created my own subclass of ColumnFixture that stores each row's input columns in a Map. For each row the column names are used as the Map's keys.

Clone https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures and take a look at  [nl.hsac.fitnesse.fixture.fit.MapColumnFixture](https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/wiki/5.-Fit-Fixtures). If your Fixture subclasses this you can get the headers as getCurrentRowValues().keySet().